# How to automate website login that uses 2-step verification using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, authentication

I'm using python selenium to automate user login for a website. However, this specific website uses a 2-step authentication when logging in: After clicking login, it then sends a code to your email address, which you have to enter into the website in order to authenticate. Any ideas what I should do or how I can access that code using python selenium?

Comment: [Selenium Docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/two_factor_authentication/) says thats its not super easy or recommended. Could you maybe use selenium to grab the code from your email as well?

Comment: python should be able to read a pop/imap mailbox fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should log in to the website in the traditional way with selenium.
2. Now the site will ask for the verification -> So you need to read your mails somehow.

I see 2 good ways to solve this:

- Login to the email service with selenium in other window or tab -> Open emails-> Select the right email -> Read out the verification code with a **regex** argument from the email content.

OR

- You can read your emails with **IMAP** -> Select the correct email with IMAP -> Once again: Read out the verification code with a **regex** argument from the email content.

3. Now you got the verification code simply write it in and log in.

Comment: I would suggest NOT using browser to open your email and to directly connect to pop/imap directly via python.

Comment: I would strongly not suggest doing it on the personal email either. But there is no other solution if he wanna automate a 2 step verification.

Comment: That's not what I suggested. I meant connect using pop/imap rather than via the browser. It will be quicker. Also consider using mail hog to intercept mails in your dev environment.